# Stop execution of code after returning response in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to Node JS. I am practising to build a MERN app. I have two function `getUserById` and `isSignedIn`. These two function are middlewares.

```
router.param("userId",getUserById)

const getUserById = (req,res,next,id)=>{
    User.findById(id).exec((err,user)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.json({
                error:"Unable to process request",
                status: false,
            })
        }
        console.log(1234);
        
        if(!user){
            return res.json({
                error:"User doesn't exist",
                status: false
            })
        }
        req.user=user;
        next()
    })
}

const isSignedIn = (req,res,next)=>{
   const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
   jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, (err, decoded)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.json({
                status: false,
                error: "Invalid Token"
            })
        }
        console.log(123);
        req.auth=decoded
        next()
   })
};

router.post("/api/create/:userId",isSignedIn,(req,res)=>{ res.send("Success")})
```

This is my understanding. If in url `userId` is found `getUserById` will be executed and then isSigned in. In `getUserById` if there was an error or if the user doesn't exist if will send a response and the execution of code stop there. But in `isSignedin` if the token is not valid I am sending a response as `Invalid Token` and the code execution should stop there. But the code after `if` is also getting executed why it is so?

Comment: **It simply cannot happen.** Add 2 more `console.log`, one before the if statement and one inside. Then run the code and show me the log from the terminal and if there are all 3 logs i'm quitting my job because i obviously know nothing about javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Try following code

```
router.param("userId",getUserById)

const getUserById = async (req,res,next,id)=>{

    try {
        const user = await User.findById(id)

        if(!user){
            return res.json({
                error:"User doesn't exist",
                status: false
            })
        } else {
            req.user=user;
            next()
        }

    } catch (err) {
        return res.json({
            error:"Unable to process request",
            status: false,
            error: JSON.stringify(err),
        })
    }
}

const isSignedIn = async (req,res,next)=>{
   const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]

   try {
    const decoded = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY)
    if (decoded) {
        req.auth=decoded
        next() 
    }
   } catch (err) {
    if(err){
        return res.json({
            status: false,
            error: "Invalid Token"
        })
    }
   }
};

router.post("/api/create/:userId",isSignedIn,(req,res)=>{ res.send("Success")})
```

Comment: Why? What did you change? How does it work?